# Terraform Cloudwatch Log Group with KMS key

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am struggling to resolve an issue of deploying an AWS log group with a KMS key associated to it.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "main" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0

  name              = module.cloudwatch_name_generator.id
  name_prefix       = var.name_prefix
  retention_in_days = var.retention_in_days
  kms_key_id        = var.kms_key_id

  tags = var.tags
}
```

I am then calling this module:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "terratest" {
  description             = "Ths key is for testing only"
  deletion_window_in_days = 7
  enable_key_rotation     = true
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "terratest" {
  name          = "alias/cloud-watch-terratest"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.terratest.key_id
}

module "cloudwatch_log_group" {
  source            = "../../modules/log-group"
  depends_on = [
    aws_kms_key.terratest
  ]
  namespace         = "blah"
  application       = "blah"
  environment       = "blah"
  retention_in_days = 7
  kms_key_id        = aws_kms_key.terratest.key_id
}
```

I get the following error:

```
│ Error: creating CloudWatch Logs Log Group (blah-blah-blah-cloudwatch-log-group): InvalidParameterException: The specified KMS Key Id could not be found.
```

Can anyone point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: They are in a different regions, right? Also, have you configured the KMS key policy? These are just a couple of ideas that come to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

KMS Key ID requires the KMS Key Arn.   Not the ID

```
kms_key_id        = aws_kms_key.terratest.arn
```